# utnable to Instentiate and Array of class in Class constructor

Tags: c#

I have to classes 1.`Cell` 2.`Grid` basically I have an array of  the cell class declared as a property in the Grid Class. How ever I am not able to instantiate the array of cell in the Grid Class Constructor. Below is my Code and the Compilation Error I am getting is 
Error   1   Method name expected which is caused by the line 
**this.Matrix = new Cell3,3;**

here is my code:

```
namespace TicTacToe
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    class Grid : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    {
        public Cell[,] Matrix { get; set; }
        public char First { get; set; }
        public char Current { get; set; }

        public bool GameOver { get; set; }
        public int MoveCounter { get; set; }

        public Grid()
        {
            this.Matrix = new Cell[3, 3]();
            this.First = 'X';
            this.Current = 'X';
            this.GameOver = false;
            this.MoveCounter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**here is my cell class**

```
namespace TicTacToe
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Drawing;

    class Cell
    {
        public char Display { get; set; }

        public Color Color { get; set; }

        public int Priority { get; set; }


        public Cell()
        {
            this.Display = ' ';
            this.Color = Color.Black;
            this.Priority = -1;
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: this.Matrix = new Cell[3, 3];  <- no parens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use parentheses when creating an array with `new`.

Change

```cs
this.Matrix = new Cell[3, 3]();
```

To

```cs
this.Matrix = new Cell[3, 3];
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was says, the good code to instantiate a multi dimensional array is:

```
this.Matrix = new Cell[3, 3];
```

But be careful, the array is created but it is empty.

You should populate it :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        Matrix[i,j] = new Cell();
    }
}
```

Or more generic:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Matrix.Length; i++)
{
    Matrix.SetValue(new Cell(), i);
}
```